Missing libQt5Xml from NixOS's qt5.qtbase?
I am running Nixos and I wanted to run a application that didn't have a config built for it. This is my OS version:

And here is my config file:
`
{ stdenv, lib, fetchurl, makeDesktopItem, qt5, wrapQtAppsHook }:
stdenv.mkDerivation rec {
  pname = "MultiMC";
  version = "1.6.1";

  meta = with lib; {
    description = "MultiMC: A custom launcher for Minecraft";
    homepage    = "https://multimc.org/";
    license     = licenses.asl20;
    platforms   = platforms.linux;
    maintainers = [ ];
  };

  src = fetchurl {
    url = "https://files.multimc.org/downloads/mmc-stable-lin64.tar.gz";
    sha256 = "BYV3jD6ejNUdMkr2xpRpQ582qIVx74O+RK4B/P790lE=";
  };

  nativeBuildInputs = [
    wrapQtAppsHook
  ];
  buildInputs = [
    qt5.qtbase
    qt5.qtbase.out.libQt5Xml
  ];
  dontWrapQtApps = true;
  unpackPhase = ''
    mkdir -p $out
    tar -xzf $src -C $out
    chmod +x $out/MultiMC/bin/MultiMC
  '';
  installPhase = ''
    runHook preInstall
    mkdir -p $out/share/applications
    runHook postInstall
  '';
  preFixup = ''
   wrapQtApp "$out/MultiMC/bin/MultiMC"
  '';
}`

And when I run the application I get this error:

But the lib is there!

How do I reference the libQt5Xml lib correctly? I have remove the qt5.qtbase.out.libQt5Xml requirement from the buildInput. That builds but then the app fails to launch.
